# How to place UIImageView over the navigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[image]

I'm trying to get the black circle to go on top of the red Nav Bar but am lost for how to achieve. This is what I have so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Adding the button
    let buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "button")

    var buttonView : UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView(image: buttonImage)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.maxX - 100, y: -100, width: 200, height: 200)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }

    super.view.addSubview(buttonView)
}
```

Comment: is that a navigation bar or a tableViewHeader?

Comment: it's a Navigation bar. I'm reading around and some say that it has to do with the scope of the view. If that's the case, how can I get it so that the top half of the circle fades in as a UIimage whenever the tableview is scrolled to the top? I'm assuming you'd have to have another copy of the image and just crop, but what would the animation look like and how would I detect the bar expanding? At the moment, the circle scrolls away with the table, which I actually think is cool, so as long as I can get the entire thing to show when I'm positioned the same as the image, that'd be fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. This should put the image on top of the nav bar.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//Adding the button

    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(buttonView)
    let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar 

    // use this navBar to set your framing and constraints

   let buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "button")

    var buttonView : UIImageView {
    let view = UIImageView(image: buttonImage)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.maxX - 100, y: -100, width: 200, height: 200)
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    return view
}

}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your comment! your code solved the issue of the image not showing over the navigation bar, but now the image is huge and I can't resize or change the coordinates of the image! I'm trying to manipulate it through CGRect....

Comment: figured it out. Thanks mate